# How can you generate a PFM signal for an LLC converter?

Tags: arduino, stm32, pwm, modulation

I am researching resonant DC/DC converters that use [PFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-frequency_modulation) (Pulse Frequency Modulation).

Before that, I was only familiar with PWM modulation, which I could generate at a given frequency from an Arduino or STM32.

**Question:** how is PFM usually generated?

Does this require separate IC's or can I implement this on Arduino / STM32?

Unfortunately StackExchange doesn't see the PFM tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I read that Wikipedia article correctly, the introduction sounds a lot like pulse density modulation (keeping a fixed pulse width) while the paragraph about buck converters keeps a fixed 50 % duty cycle. Could you clarify which one you want to implement? Both can be implemented with a GPTC of the STM32 I think, I'm just a little confused.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand correctly, it looks like a regular PWM with a fixed duty cycle of 50%. Only here we can quickly change the frequency (I also haven't found a lot of information about PFM yet).

Answer (score 1):

> *how is PFM usually generated?*

You keep mark-space ratio at 50% (optional of course) and vary the frequency of the square wave.

> *Does this require separate IC's or can I implement this on Arduino /
> STM32?*

For PWM it's very convenient if you have an MCU with pulse width modulation features. For PFM, in a basic form, you need to set up a loop that that can accept as an input a variable that defines how long the loop takes to execute thus varying the time duration. Counter/timers help a lot and can produce an interrupt when the loop end-count is reached.

Comment: Thank you! So PFM is a regular PWM (with a fixed duty cycle), in which we simply change the frequency at any time through the registers.

Comment: That's it basically but, the duty cycle can play a role in many DC/DC converters such as those where the "on" pulse is kept at a constant time period and only the off time is varied. In effect this is still a form of pulse frequency modulation and the outcome is that the duty cycle automatically increases when the frequency is increased. Maybe read this: https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/articles/the-advantages-of-pulse-frequency-modulation-for-dc-dc-switching-voltage-converters?_ga=2.102064007.741902148.1599053997-90677768.1594820024

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer!